# Winforms Tags Component

Tags: c#, winforms, components

Tags wouldn't be the correct word for what I'm looking for, but for lack of a better choice, it's what I've used. What I'd like to know is if there's a component or anything I can use that will create an input similar to this site's tags field.

[image: Tags Field]

Basically I would like a field exactly like the one used here. As you type in a list of possible options becomes available and once one is selected, you can continue to select another. Unless it's under a name I have not yet thought of, I have not been able to find one in any of my searches.

Is there anyway I can get what I want?

Comment: Try http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/TokenEditorControl.aspx

Comment: that is very simple to do it by yourself, one way is to create a class that inherits `Label` and write code to provide the features you need (text, image, click event handler to dispose the object etc... ). also you can add your custom "Tag" objects to a `FlowLayoutPanel` control and i will behave the same as it appears in the picture

Comment: It is simply a Checkbox, with Appearance = Button, FlatStyle = Flat and an Image that indicates the check state.

Comment: i think you could do something like this with a panel containing a listview to the left and a textbox to the right

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment, its very simple to do it by yourself 
(took me only ~15 min to write you the example below) here is a **code example+output** for start - "Tag label" object with a button to dispose himself, please read my comments inside.

**clarification**: this code needs improvements to be adapted to all possible cases but you can learn from it the basic idea of how to create a custom control.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Padding = New Padding(3, 3, 3, 3)

        Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
        Dim size As SizeF
        ' check how much width needed for the string "Winforms"...'
        size = g.MeasureString("Winforms", Me.Font)

        Dim tagwinforms As New TagObject("Winforms", size.Width + TagObject.BtnRemoveWidth + 20, FlowLayoutPanel1.Height - 8)
        tagwinforms.Init()
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(tagwinforms)

        ' check how much width needed for the string "C#"...'
        size = g.MeasureString("C#", Me.Font)

        Dim tagcsharp As New TagObject("C#", size.Width + TagObject.BtnRemoveWidth + 20, FlowLayoutPanel1.Height - 8)
        tagcsharp.Init()
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(tagcsharp)

        g.Dispose()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class TagObject
    Inherits Label
    Public Shared Property BtnRemoveWidth As Int16 = 20
    Public Shared Property BtnRemoveHeight As Int16 = 20
    ' note: you can add get set methods and in the set method you can change value in runtime '
    Public Property DescriptionText As String
    Private Property TagHeight As Int16
    Private Property TagWidth As Int16
    Private btnRemove As PictureBox

    ' you can add any property you need backcolor forecolor etc...'
    Sub New(ByVal descriptionText As String, ByVal width As Int16, ByVal height As Integer)
        Me.DescriptionText = descriptionText
        Me.TagHeight = height
        Me.TagWidth = width
        Me.Font = New Font("ARIAL", 8, FontStyle.Bold)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Init()
        Me.Text = DescriptionText
        Me.Width = TagWidth
        Me.Height = TagHeight
        Me.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30)
        Me.ForeColor = Color.White
        btnRemove = New PictureBox()
        btnRemove.Height = BtnRemoveHeight
        btnRemove.Width = BtnRemoveWidth
        btnRemove.Location = New Point(TagWidth - btnRemove.Width - 1, TagHeight / 2 - btnRemove.Height / 2)
        ' original image url: https://www.google.co.il/search?q=close+icon+free&safe=off&rlz=1C1ASUM_enIL700IL700&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVuJnbk5vZAhXKesAKHRXqDX8Q_AUICigB&biw=1440&bih=769#imgrc=2p_iHiqieStqCM:'
        btnRemove.Image = My.Resources.CloseIcon
        btnRemove.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
        AddHandler btnRemove.Click, AddressOf btnRemove_Click
        Me.Controls.Add(btnRemove)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' the user wants to delete this tag...'
        Me.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Output:**
[image]